# Jquery/CSS3 transition links work only partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is my links will transition, but on the `register` link it won't transition back. Click the `"You have an account already? Log in here"` link and watch it transition clearly, but then click the `"You don't have an account yet? Register here"` link and you see the issue   - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8X9H/95/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the class `.register` on your first form - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8X9H/96/)

```
<form class="container register active" method="post">
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, just needed an extra set of eyeballs! Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Accept? Sure, how? I'm new to this